# Is there a 3D format which is a 3D extension to SVG?

Tags: xml, svg, 3d, w3c, blender

SVG is the W3C's standard for 2D vector graphics. Something quite solid. Is there a 3D version of SVG? A kind of extension of it, so converting from `.svg` to `.ext` and reverse is quite straight forward programatically.

Comment: Well, I'am on purpose splitting it into 2 different questions : a. 2D to 3D process, b. 3D format. Related but not duplicates.

Comment: There is VRML - which is a non-XML based 3D modeling standard - but it's not widely supported.

Comment: @Phrogz: this question and the other one are *not* duplicates, could you remove the "`This question may already have an answer here:
How to convert 2D vector (SVG) representing relief to 3D vector file?`" flag over the question.

Comment: @Hugolpz Now that you have clarified and split the two questions better, I have removed my comment. However, as I am not a moderator, I cannot remove my single close vote. I encourage others to ignore that vote at this point, as this question and the other have been mutated to be clearly separate.

Comment: There are examples of 3d in svg if you are willing to do the math.
https://prideout.net/blog/svg_wireframes/

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no such standard extension to SVG as part of the W3C.

The closest that exists is the W3C Community Group, *["Declarative 3D for the Web Architecture Community Group"](http://www.w3.org/community/declarative3d/)*.

---

*Editorial: nor should there be. While SVG is great and vector, it is a presentation format, not a data-interchange format as you seek for 3D. For example, the painter's model of SVG describes the visual layering of elements, a concept that is unrelated to the vector data. Similarly is the presentation markup on fill and stroke color/opacity, instead of metadata such as material. Though it's not a great format IMHO, you should look at [COLLADA](https://collada.org) if you want an XML-based file format for 3D data.*

Comment: It would be useful to have 3d objects which are rendered in 2d for schematics That way, a single object can be viewed in 2d for schematic diagrams but represented as a single object supporting multiple perspectives. Right now, each perspective needs it's own set of objects leading to combinatorics of object count * perspective count.

Answer (score 7):

If the W3C feature of SVG is critical, I don't know of anything.  And if you want to make an SVG graphic into 3D by changing some outer tags and leaving the rest alone, I don't know of anything either.

But if what you like about SVG is that it is a declarative language for 2D graphics that can be rendered in a browser, and furthermore that the objects are "persistent" in the sense that you can change an attribute in the DOM and that change is reflected in the browser (in contrast to a canvas approach where making a change means redrawing the picture), then X3D is a candidate.  They [appear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D#Standardization) to have liaison and cooperation agreements with W3C etc.  Javascript libraries support rendering in a browser; see demos at [X3dom](https://www.x3dom.org/), [Cobweb](http://titania.create3000.de/cobweb/).